# Laravel admin edit route not working. Returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, admin

After trying with `Route::resource` and `Route::name('admin.')`, it seems that when I want to edit a user through `localhost/admin/{id}/edit` it returns to me  404 error. If i remove the "admin" on the route in web.php it works perfectly but I don't want like this because I have two entities with an edit route.

**Web.php**

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');

/* Route::get('{username}/edit', ['as' => 'admin.edit', 'uses' => 'AdminController@edit']); */
```

**AdminController.php**

```
public function edit($admin) {

    $user = User::where('user',$admin)-> first();

    return view('admin.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

Edit:

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <style> .uper {margin-top: 40px;} </style>

    <div class="card uper">
        <div class="card-header">
            Update Shows
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div><br/>
            @endif
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.update', $user->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PATCH')
                    <label for="name">Nom:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="user">Usuari:</label>
                    <input id="user" type="text" class="form-control @error('user') is-invalid @enderror" name="user" value="{{ $user->user }}" required autocomplete="user" autofocus>
                    @error('user') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"> <strong>{{ $message }}</strong> </span> @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Correu:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}"/>
                    @error('email') <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"> <strong>{{ $message }}</strong> </span> @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="avatar" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Avatar (optional)') }}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="avatar" type="file" class="form-control" name="avatar">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualitzar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**route:list**

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                  | admin.index      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index                             | web,roles    |
|        | POST      | admin                  | admin.store      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@store                             | web,roles    |
|        | POST      | admin/crear            |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,roles    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/crear            | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,roles    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/create           | admin.create     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@create                            | web,roles    |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/{admin}          | admin.update     | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@update                            | web,roles    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{admin}          | admin.show       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@show                              | web,roles    |
|        | DELETE    | admin/{admin}          | admin.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@destroy                           | web,roles    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{admin}/edit     | admin.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@edit                              | web,roles    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | PATCH     | empresa/{id}           | empresa.update   | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@updateCompany                   | web,roles    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | empresa/{id}           | empresa.show     | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@showCompany                     | web,roles    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | empresa/{id}/edit      | empresa.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@editCompany                     | web,roles    |
|        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web          |
|        | POST      | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | perfil                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web          |
|        | POST      | {user}                 | post.store       | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | {user}/create          |                  | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@create                             | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | {user}/{category}/{id} | post.show        | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@show                               | web,auth     |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Edit 2:

With **empresa.edit** the same thing happens.

**Edit 3:**

If I modify the route removing the admin prefix, it works, but I want the admin on the url:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController')->except(['edit']);
Route::get('{username}/edit', ['as' => 'admin.edit', 'uses' => 'AdminController@edit']);
```

Comment: Can you please show the form code.
Did you pass method as put?

Comment: Could you please show list routs(php artisan route:list)?

Comment: @Remul `Route::resource('admin')` actually creates an `admin/{admin}/edit`  route

Comment: @Dmitry I added the routes.

Comment: @NikitaVagadiya that isn't the problem. It doesn't return the view.

Comment: I think the problem is here - if (is_null($user)){abort(404);}

Comment: @Dmitry Unfortunately that's not the problem. I removed that and placed a ```dd($user)``` instead but It keeps returning the same 404 error. Also I cleared the cache, but is not working.

Comment: @Dherevo
Please show how you are calling the edit method in view and try dd("here") on begining of the edit method

Comment: is this a laravel 404 error or your webservers 404 error? do you have a folder named `admin` in your `public` folder?

Comment: @NikitaVagadiya  I tried to change with another view but I think the problem is in the controller or in the route.               ```<a href="{{ route('admin.edit', $user->user)}}">Edit</a>```

Comment: @lagbox Laravel 404 error and I don't have an admin folder in public.

Comment: you are trying to find the user by a field named 'user' or 'id'?

Comment: @Dherevo what is *$user->user* i guess it should be the id *$user->id*

Comment: @lagbox I modified that because before this I was searching by id, but now I'm searching with username. In both ways it doesn't works.

Comment: @NikitaVagadiya I'm searching by username, but it doesn't works too.

Comment: Could you remove - abort(404);

Comment: @Dmitry I removed before, but it's the same. With this code it keeps returning me an a 404 error 

```$user = User::where('user',$admin)-> first(); dd($user);```

 I think the problem is in the route because it doesn't get the ```dd($user); ``` in the controller.

Comment: Another urls are woking?

Comment: @Dmitry all of them, except empresa.edit that it's the same than admin.edit

Comment: How you create route resource?

Comment: You can try remove controller. Then create(php artisan make:controller AdminController --resource) and add in web.php (Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController'); I checked it's working

Comment: @Dmitry I deleted the Controller but It's still giving me 404 after creating again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it by myself. It's because the order of the routes in **web.php**. Since I have a route like `/{user}/create` before the `Route::resource`, so that's causing the problem. Anyway thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

check directory public . if exist admin dir rename .